# Table Creation Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am creating a few as per a customers request and I have a statement and I am wondering if it is going to fail or if I need to add some lines of code so it won't fail.

```
CREATE TABLE AuditReport
(
    AR_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TPPRM_ID NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vendor(TPPRM_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    OR_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OversightResults(OR_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    AR_ReportNAme NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    AR_Version NVARCHAR(7),
    AR_Type NVARCHAR(20),
    AR_DateCoveragePeriod DATETIME2,
    AR_DateReceived DATETIME2,
    AR_Opinion NVARCHAR(11) CONSTRAINT CHK_Opinion CHECK (AR_Opinion IN ('Qualified','Unqualified')),
    AR_NextReportDate DATETIME2,
    AR_KeyContactName NVARCHAR(30),
    AR_ContactEmail NVARCHAR(40),
    AR_ContactPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(14)
)

--Create OversightResults Table
CREATE TABLE OversightResults
(
    OR_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    AR_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AuditReport(AR_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    TPPRM_ID NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vendor(TPPRM_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    OR_ServiceObjectives BIT,
    OR_Objectives BIT,
    OR_ControlsTested BIT,
    OR_ManagementUserEntity NVARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT CHK_ManagementUserEntity CHECK (OR_ManagementUserEntity IN ('Management','User')),
    OR_Controls NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OR_ServicerResponse NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OR_ArvestMitigatingControls NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OR_Deficiency NVARCHAR(10),
    OR_Recommdations NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OR_Observations NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OR_Sufficiency BIT,
    OR_RiskIdentified NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

As you can see in the table design the Audit Report table has OR_ID as a foreign key and the Oversight Results table has it as a primary key and Oversight results has AR_ID as a foreign key and Audit Report has it as the primary key. As the statement stands right now, will the Audit report table fail to create because a table with OR_ID as the primary key hasn't been created yet?

Comment: please provide the result of query execution

Comment: Trying it out would answer this, but hey. Yes. This is a circular dependency. You'll probably have to add one of the constraints after creation to get around this. Though I question whether it makes any sense to do so. Is there only ever going to be one `AuditReport` for one `OversightResult`? If yes, why not put both in the same table? If no, then the envisioned linking is not possible both ways. Also I guess `OR_Recommdations` is a typo.

Comment: You could try creating them as temp tables (put a # before the name), this way you'll see any errors without actually making the tables. Remember that you'll need to drop the tables at the end otherwise you will get errors recreating the same table next time.

Comment: @RichBenner Table variables would seem to be nicer here as they'll go out of scope automatically when the batch closes, thus not requiring manual `drop`ping (assuming I'm remembering correctly)

Comment: yeah I could run it but I only have read rights to the DB. Thanks for the help I just took away one of the foreign key dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If this really is meant to be a 1:1 relationship, just put them all in one table.  If you want, you could then create some views on that table to separate out the results, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_OversightResults AS
WITH SCHEMABINDING
SELECT
    OR_ID,
    TPPRM_ID,
    OR_ServiceObjectives,
    OR_Objectives,
    OR_ControlsTested,
    OR_ManagementUserEntity,
    OR_Controls,
    OR_ServicerResponse,
    OR_ArvestMitigatingControls,
    OR_Deficiency,
    OR_Recommdations,
    OR_Observations,
    OR_Sufficiency,
    OR_RiskIdentified
FROM AuditReport
```

And it shouldn't be too hard to make this an Indexed View if need be either...

Otherwise, you need to remove the FK from one of the two tables and add a UNIQUE index on the FK of the one that keeps it (perhaps make it part of the PK?).  But it'd be less confusing to just have it all on one table.

Answer (score 0):

This is circular dependency. Table `AuditReport` have relation to `OversightResults` and vise versa. Better to avoid this, you can merge this as a single table or you can create one more mapping table if required.
If you required this circular dependency specifically then you can follow the steps.

1. Create table `AuditReport` without a FK relation to `OversightResults`.
2. Then create `OversightResults` and relate to `AuditReport`.
3. Alter the table `AuditReport`  and add the FK relation to
   `OversightResults`.